# Newton's method to find the inflexion points of a function

Tags: calculus

Use the Newton's method to find the inflexion points of a function given by (x^3+3x^2-4)/e^x

The derivative of the function is -(x^3-6x-4)/e^x

The Newton's method has the formula xn+1=xn-(f(xn))/f'(xn)

I am unable to proceed with x0 values of 1 and -2.

What initial value should I use?Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint....To find points of inflexion you need to solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$

Comment: I know that.....but how do you do it using Newton's method?

Comment: Do you have an expression for the second derivative?

Comment: The second derivative is (x^3-3x^2-6x+2)/e^x.

Comment: So set $f(x)=$ the top line of this and apply Newton's Method. There are three possible points. Which one do you need to find?

Comment: I need to find all of them.How did you get them and what are they?

Comment: I checked on Wolfram Alpha!